# Byzantine generals (n=3, m=1)

Tags: distributed-systems, consensus

Leslie Lamport describes a algorithm to come to consensus for the case for `n>3*m`, there `m` is the number of traitors in `n` generals.

I perfectly understand why for `n=4, m=1` there is consensus trough a majority vote. Lets suppose (like in Leslies proposal) there are three type of messages for different attack time `(A1, A2, A3)`. If no majority is reached the default action is retreat (`r`).

So even if the commander is a traitor and send different messages `A1,A2,A3` to the three loyal lieutenants they will get (trough the recursive algorithm) to state (`A1,A2,A3`). In this case no majority is reached and the default action is taken (`r`). Thereby consensus is reached.

Leslie stated, that no consensus cannot be reached with `n=3, m=1`. Nonetheless if we apply the upper algorithm to the scenario with `n=3, m=1` for the example that the commander is a traitor, isn't there the same consensus reached? The commander sends `A1, A2` to the two loyal lieutenants, they both will reach the state `(A1, A2)` and thereby take the default option `r`. There is my mistake?

Comment: The [original paper](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~luca/cs174/byzantine.pdf) (of which Lamport is just one of the authors) contains a proof of impossibility in Section 2. Run this proof on your algorithm, and see what happens.

Comment: I already read this paper. This is exactly where I'm stuck. In section 2 is stated that lieutenant 1 has to follow the attack command. But in the next section a default action is introduced. Furthermore in section 2 there is also no communication from lieutenant 1 to lieutenant  2.
So from my point of view consensus can be reached if there is a default action (like in section 3) and a communication from lieutenant 1 to lieutenant 2. This is why I don't understand why no consensus can be reached for `n=3, m=1`

Comment: If the original paper is too hard to follow, try Ben-Ari's textbook [Principles of Concurrent and Distributed Programming (Second edition)](http://www.weizmann.ac.il/sci-tea/benari/research-activities/principles-concurrent-and-distributed-programming-second-edition).